# Post on Facebook application wall using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, facebook

I have created an application in facebook and I am able to post on my wall as soon as I log in to the application.  What I need is to update the application's wall as well.

For this I even granted `manage_pages extended permission`.

Here's the code which I am trying to execute

```
FB.ui({
  method: 'stream.publish',
  message: 'har lavet en sang. Hør den på dr.dk/sangskriver',
  attachment: {
    name: 'Hør min sang',
    caption: 'DR Sangskriver - Hvorfor være stille, når man kan skrive en sang...',
    description: ('DR giver dig i samarbejde med
                   musikgymnasier og Rytmekonsertoriet, dette nye sangskriversite. ' +
                  'Her har du mulighed for at lære lidt om hvordan man skriver en  
                   sang, få gode råd af allerede kendte sangskrivere om sangskrivning  
                   og offentliggøre dit værk.'
                 ),
    href: 'http://www.dr.dk/Undervisning/Sangskriver/Upload/sang?id='
  },
  action_links: [
    { text: 
        'Hør sang', href: 'http://www.dr.dk/Undervisning/Sangskriver/Upload/sang?id=' }
  ],
  target_id:131597976919961 //here I am specifying application id, as the page
             id of application is not there, I get a link like this
             http://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=131597976919961
},
  function(response) { }
)
```

But everytime it's saying it's not a valid target_id; however when I am trying to call stream.publish method from facebook api page, it's posting on my application page

Any idea what's wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Please see facebook's documentation related to stream.publish [here...](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/stream.publish/)

Quoting from the documentation it is possible to publish to the application's profile page if

> In order to use stream.publish to post
>   on the Wall of your application
>   profile page (your application's About
>   Page), all the following conditions
>   must be true: The posting user needs
>   to grant the application the
>   publish_stream extended permission.
>   The posting user must like the
>   application's profile page. A
>   developer of the application must edit
>   the application profile page's Wall
>   Settings (Edit Application > Edit) and
>   verify under Posting Ability that Fans
>   can write or post content on the wall
>   is checked.

Anyways since this api is being deprecated, you should use the new js sdk instead. Please see the documentation [here..](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.ui/)